# Mongoose async/await questions

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, async-await

Hi I'm debugging my app but got stuck and I think there's something I didn't quite grasp around how to properly handle mongoose within an async function.

So I have my main server.js that has something like

```
  const user = await userService.authenticate({ username, password });
  console.log("user in the main method is ...");
  console.log(user);
```

And I have another 'userService.js' that has something like (simplified)

```
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {  
  await Users.find({ username: username, password: password }, function(
    err,
    user
  ) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    if (user) {

      console.log("user within the authenticate method is...  ");
      console.log(user);
      return user;
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is within the `authenticate` method the console.log has the proper authenticate information, however within the main server.js I'm getting a different value. I suspect it has something to do with how I used the async and await keywords. Here's what I'm getting from my console

```
user within the authenticate method is...  
[
  {
    _id: 5ee845ee39fdf73190068308,
    username: 'XXXXXX',
    firstName: 'XXX',
    lastName: 'XXX',
    password: 'XXX',
    categoryDiscount: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
user in the main method is ...
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I get it to work after modifying the authenticate method to the following.

```
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
  console.log("starting the authenticate method");
  const user = await Users.findOne({ username: username, password: password });
  if (user) {
    console.log("user within the authenticate method is...  ");
    console.log(user);
    return user;
  }
}
```

But it's not clear why this change make things work...

Comment: This means Users.findOne supports promises. You were using callbacks, which needs to be made promises to be used with async/await. You can see my answer for promisifying authenticate(), but this option is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

await keywoard only work inside the async function. It can not be used outside it.

```
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
Users.find({ username: username, password: password }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
      return user;
    }
  });
}

async function print() {
    const user = await userService.authenticate({ username, password }); 
    console.log(user)
}
print()
```

This would print the desired result.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify - the `await` within the server.js is also within an async function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use of await in main.js is okay, what is missing is you need to return a promise in authenticate(). You don't need to make authenticate() async.

```
 function authenticate({ username, password }) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    Users.find({ username: username, password: password }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {
        // res.send(err);
        rej(err); // this error will need to be caught using try/catch in calling function
      } else {
        // we resolve the promise as long as no error was returned

        console.log("user within the authenticate method is...  ");
        console.log(user);
        //return user;
        res(user); // user returned to calling function
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Await` is use to wait that a promise resolve.  It does not return or halt the execution of a function.  Here the `authenticate` function does not return anything.  V8 knows this is a promise but since there is no return, the value that resolve from `await userService.authenticate({ username, password });` will be `undefined`.  Using this logic then the following code will work

```
function authenticate({ username, password }) {
  return Users.findOne({ username: username, password: password })
}
// or
async function authenticate({ username, password }) {
  const user = await Users.findOne({ username: username, password: password })
  return user

}
// or 
function authenticate({ username, password }) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     Users.findOne({ username: username, password: password },function(err,user) 
       {
          if(err) return reject(err)
          return resolve(user)

       })
  })
}
```